# Hardcoded string and assigned string acts differently

Tags: prawn

Working with ruby 1.9.3 --> when rendering text pdf.text "Hello \n World" it works as advertised.

However, if i pass it as a parameter from ARGV " \n " is just being displayed as text and not CR.

Checked encoding. both US-ASCII.

Any ideas?

Comment: Found the problem, ARGV \n are passed as \\n . Can someone help me convert it back?

Answer (score 0):

"Hello '\n' World" - hope this helps)